# Why are summation/product operators not much welcomed as being part of closed form expressions, even if they have finite terms?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, meta-math

I read somewhere that in most closed form expressions, which are expressions used to calculate a certain outcome with only finite terms, summation/product operators are mostly neglected. I can understand if it was in case of infinite summations or multiplication, but even finite summations and prods are not considered closed form.

What is a suitable justification for that?

Comment: They might be usually really small like $x\approx 0$. Anything else would be hard to say without specifically  knowing which terms are you talking about.

Comment: https://brilliant.org/wiki/closed-form-expressions/

Comment: My guess, and certainly something that I like to stick to, is that a closed-form expression should desierably be expressed in terms of elementary functions. Seeing as many finite summations  do not themselves have closed-form expressions, it does not make sense to include these in closed-form expressions. TL;DR: when a summation or product can be simplified, it is; otherwise, it isn't really closed-form since it is not in terms of elementary functions.

Answer (score 2):

I would differentiate whether the number of terms in the variable is an absolute constant or a variable itself. So $\sum_{k=1}^n k$ is not a closed form expression, although it contains only finitely many terms. I would call $\sum_{k=1}^3 k$ a closed form expression, this is just a question of convenient notation (which is pointless in this specific example but could be useful in more complex situations).